# Is there a way of determining how many and which users were active on a given day?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there away of determining how many and which users were active on a given day?

Without of course visiting the individual profile pages.

Comment: Try to search queries on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is also [Number of active experts per week](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/581626/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph) available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define *active* more precise but I have taken the users that either post or edit or leave a comment and then created [this SEDE Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/591307#graph)

```
select activedate
     , count(*) [# users]
from
(
select distinct cast(creationdate as date) as [activedate]
     , owneruserid
from
(
select creationdate 
     , owneruserid 
from posts
union 
select lasteditdate 
     , lasteditoruserid
from posts 
union
select creationdate
     , userid
from comments
) data
) uniquerows
group by activedate
order by activedate
```

You can extend this query to also include events from the posthistory table and suggested edits. See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for the possibilities.

When run today this is what the graph looks like:

[image: graph of user counts per day]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday. If you have more questions that can be answered with queries against the SEDE database, consider asking them on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer). They already have a bunch of queries ready and if none of the existing ones fulfill your need there are enough users around that are prepared to take on these query requests.

Comment: Do you know a ready-made query for this: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/728. Thanks.

Comment: @sv. No, I don't. Not all data presented on Area 51 in the statistic is available in SEDE (due to missing history/deleted items). But feel free to bring it up on MSE as some of the statistics can be queried.